# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-blob-util:compileDebugAidl' (React Native)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, build

I am facing this error on istalling new packges in my react native when i install react-native-blob-util an run android app and facing the follwing error

```
 What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-blob-util:compileDebugAidl'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException (no error message)
```

I am laso getting same erorr on installing react-native-splash-screen

```
 What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-splash-screen:compileDebugAidl'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException (no error message)
```

here is the full error

```
Warning: SDK processing. package.xml parsing problem. Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1465)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1013)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-blob-util:compileDebugAidl'.
> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 22s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Package.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.7",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.6",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.4",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.2",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.3.25",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.27.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.0",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.0.1"
  },
}
```

How I can fix this issue??